# Unable to install time module using npm

Tags: npm, time

I am trying to install necessary dependencies for project. When installing time module getting the following error. I have tried updating npm and gyp rebuild, but didn't solve the problem. Can someone give me a solution for this?

```
I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram>npm install time

> time@0.12.0 install I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time
> node-gyp rebuild


I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Administrator.Sameeh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) 
 else (node "C:\Users\Administrator.Sameeh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
  time.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(12): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Handle' [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(16): error C2065: 'target': undeclared identifier [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(19): error C2065: 'target': undeclared identifier [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(22): error C2065: 'target': undeclared identifier [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(25): error C2065: 'target': undeclared identifier [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(87): error C2660: 'v8::Value::IntegerValue': function does not take 0 arguments [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
  c:\users\administrator.sameeh\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.13.1\include\node\v8.h(2609): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value ::IntegerValue' (compiling source file ..\src\time.cc)
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(141): error C2660: 'v8::Value::Int32Value': function does not take 0 arguments [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
  c:\users\administrator.sameeh\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.13.1\include\node\v8.h(2613): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value ::Int32Value' (compiling source file ..\src\time.cc)
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(142): error C2660: 'v8::Value::Int32Value': function does not take 0 arguments [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
  c:\users\administrator.sameeh\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.13.1\include\node\v8.h(2613): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value::Int32Value' (compiling source file ..\src\time.cc)
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(143): error C2660: 'v8::Value::Int32Value': function does not take 0 arguments [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
  c:\users\administrator.sameeh\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.13.1\include\node\v8.h(2613): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value ::Int32Value' (compiling source file ..\src\time.cc)
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(144): error C2660: 'v8::Value::Int32Value': function does not take 0 arguments [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
  c:\users\administrator.sameeh\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.13.1\include\node\v8.h(2613): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value ::Int32Value' (compiling source file ..\src\time.cc)
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(145): error C2660: 'v8::Value::Int32Value': function does not take 0 arguments [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
  c:\users\administrator.sameeh\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.13.1\include\node\v8.h(2613): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value ::Int32Value' (compiling source file ..\src\time.cc)
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(146): error C2660: 'v8::Value::Int32Value': function does not take 0 arguments [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
  c:\users\administrator.sameeh\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.13.1\include\node\v8.h(2613): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value::Int32Value' (compiling source file ..\src\time.cc)
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(147): error C2660: 'v8::Value::Int32Value': function does not take 0 arguments [I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]
  c:\users\administrator.sameeh\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.13.1\include\node\v8.h(2613): note: see declaration of 'v8::Value::Int32Value' (compiling source file ..\src\time.cc)
i:\blog application\streamingprogram\node_modules\time\src\time.cc(156): error C2065: 'Handle': undeclared identifier [I:\Blog Ap    plication\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time\build\time.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with
exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Administrator.Sameeh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrator.Sameeh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd I:\Blog Application\StreamingProgram\node_modules\time
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! time@0.12.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the time@0.12.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: 191 time viewed and no answers, did you resolve it? @Sameeh KP